# Did I implement this function with a MUX correctly?

Tags: multiplexer

I have this truth table:

[image]

Which gives this SOP

```
y = A'B'C + A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC
```

I tried to use a MUX with 2 selects and 4 inputs and I got this (using A and B as the selectors):

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's correct because when I light up A, B and C according to the truth table I get the right value for Y but I just want to make sure.

Comment: First of all, have you checked the datasheet for this chip? Secondly, it's hard to understand what you're trying to do. A MUX device is supposed to stream a serial output of bits depending on the data selection you assign. **I really don't think you're using this MUX for its intended purpose.**

Comment: @KingDuken I have. It's a multiplexer. D0-D7 are inputs, A,B and C are selector, with A being the least significant one. Y and W are outputs, S is enable. What I am trying to do is use a mux to implement that SOP. Or at least that's what my professor wants us to do.

Comment: @KingDuken there are techniques to use multiplxer to implement arbitrary logic. Presumably the question is about that way of using a multiplexer.

Comment: @KingDuken Multiplexers are used to implement combinational logic in FPGAs. There's no reason to assume that the output is "serial" data.

Comment: Oh I think understand what's happening now. I was reading A,B, C on the data selects, not the buttons. My apologies. In that case, give me more time to look at it :) Labeling your buttons should not be "A B C", you should label those inputs differently to avoid confusion. I still believe you should have a look over the datasheet to double check your work.

Comment: You are using a 8-input mux that has 3 select lines. There is no need for the added inverter. Why are you ignoring the full functionality of the device.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson My professor wants us to use this chip as a mux with 4 inputs and 2 selectors. Forgot to mention that

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire  Good  but Elliot is saying you can do it with just ABC inputs then D1=D3=D5=D7=1 else 0  (no inv.needed)

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Then why doesn't the professor have you use one of the duals found in either a 74153 or a 74253? Only have 74151? Or is the professor also wanting to force you to use something with complementary output, too?

Comment: @jonk I have no idea. I was looking through last years exam for practice and one of the questions was "The number [number in hex] has 12 bits in its binary 2's complement form, how much is it in binary?"

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Have you noticed that your **Y** output basically looks like an XOR? **Y** is essentially just a 1-bit sum of A, B, and C.

Comment: @jonk I have. One of the questions was exactly to convert this SOP into an XOR

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Well, your circuit does what you are supposed to make it do. So, that's good!

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Also looks like you are using Neemann's Digital. Good!! That's the best available for things like this, right now. You should add in test vectors to your schematic. That way, you have automatic verification.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire [This screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzL6Q.png) shows what I mean. Digital makes it very easy to add this feature. All eight of those text vector lines could also be replaced with just one line: "repeat(8) bits(3,n) (((n>>2)+((n>>1)&1)+(n&1))&1)".

Comment: @jonk Oh. I tried doing that but overcomplicated it so I gave up. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> y = A'B'C + A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC

Given  [image] to  implement with 8:1 mux. with 3 address inputs.

```
y=1 ABC
    001 = d1 =>"1"
    010 = d2 =>"1" 
    100 = d4 =>"1"
    111 = d7 =>"1"
y = 0 for d0=d3=d5=d6="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a correct implementation of the 3-bit parity function to me.

you've used an 8:1 mux instead of 4:1, but as you're only using 2 of the address lines  I guess that's ok.

As jstola says writing it in logic diagrams instead of wiring may be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.

Please get accustomed to using logic symbols instead of using a wiring diagram as you have in your question.

It will make your life easier when the circuits get more complicated.

Here is a random example from the web.

[image]